# Why is 5 != 5.0000000000000000001 False, but 5 != 5.00000001 True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, comparison-operators

In python 3.5, I was just playing around with comparison operators and came across this (seeming) oddity.

Is there a threshold of number of zeros after the decimal point past which the interpreter decides to not consider values relevant because of the inherent inaccuracy of floating point values?

Comment: Precision is limited, yes. Not exactly in the number of *decimal* digits though, so if you look at it as though it is, the precision will appear to vary.

Comment: @harold, but when you *give* python two values to compare, there are no calculations to make (as in I'm not asking python to add, subtract, etc...two floating point values), so why can't it figure out that 5 != 5.000000000000000001?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I think the question is different because the context is comparison operators, although it's obviously related. In this case I'm asking why python can't figure out that 5.0000000000000000001 is not 5, not why python returns approximations when computing FPV's. Not sure it was worth an instant downvote...(not saying it was you, but whoever it was it'd be nice to get an explanation).

Comment: @jeremyradcliff well they're not strings, so clearly there's (implicitly) a parsing step. Since they become true floats, they become limited to that precision.

Comment: @harold, thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: If you're up for it, look into [`float_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L344) he's responsible for this operation. I generally think this is a nice Q.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard, thank you. It's probably beyond my current skills to grasp all of what's in that function, but I think I can gain a lot by going through it slowly and trying nonetheless.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I agree. Info could be posted as answer?

Comment: @XamuelSchulman I wouldn't feel comfortable doing that. I'd like to see it  explained, I'm trying to explain it to myself first and then I'll post an answer (If someone doesn't beat me to it :-)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Of course. I meant just that at some point all this could be put together into an answer instead of a bunch of comments.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: None of the stuff in `float_richcompare` is interesting in the context of this question, though; everything relevant happens in the source code->float conversion step. The code path for `float_richcompare` in the `some_float == some_other_float` case boils down to a C-level `==` check.

Comment: @user2357112 certain? care to explain in an answer? I was confident the cause was in the `richcompare`.

Comment: ok, just did `float(5.0000000000000000000000001)` and `float(5.00001)` and got my answer :-) that's what I get for going straight to the operation

Comment: No, the question is not different. Python can't figure out that 5.0000000000000000001 is not 5 *because* Python returns approximations when interpreting FPVs. Just set `x = 5.0000000000000000001` then look at the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, during the phase were parsing of input is done, Python needs to transform your input to a `C double` which can then be transformed to a Python `float`. Inputs with more [than 16 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) are going to get approximated, with `5.0000000000000001` getting approximated to `5.0`:

```
>>> 5.0000000000000001 
5.0
```

As a result the comparison `5 == 5.0000000000000001` is going to succeed (`5` is going to get transformed to a Python float equal to `5.0` in order for the comparison to take place).

For digits less than the aforementioned, the result (can be represented) and speaks for itself:

```
>>> 5.000000000000001
5.000000000000001
```

Yes, `float_richcompare` has --unfortunately-- nothing to do with this behavior as I thought in my original comment on the question. It all happens before it gets invoked.

Comment: Thank you for writing a complete answer, this is very helpful; I had no idea python was going through the process of turning the input into a C double.

Comment: Why "unfortunately"? You surely wouldn't want an equality comparison of floats to do some kind of fuzzy comparison: it would mess up transitivity of equality, and hence set and dict containment, etc.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I initially though this was something `float_richcompare` did i.e I missed that ` 5.0000000000000001` is going to get approximated to `5.0` by `float_new`;. I thought that happened in `richcompare`. The "unfortunately" directs to my "swing and miss" comment under the question :-)

Comment: Well, not *any* input with more than 16 digits: E.g., 5.0000000000000005 is not 5.

Comment: @RickRegan the wording was ambiguous, updated that to better describe what I meant to say.